# gitlab SSL giving issues

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I am trying to configure SSL in the GitLab (Latest) in centos 7 as per the document below:

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html

But doing so I am encountering the below error:

```
4510076352:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 320 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Looking for help.

I have used Let's Encrypt wild card certificate. The certificate is working fine for NGINX. But in Gitlab it's giving issues.